# React - Download image from url without saving it to filesystem and send it to Node Api

Tags: reactjs

We have requirement where we have to read 1-10000 image URL from one location. Sample array

```js
[
    {
        "asin": "B00HZ9Q8XM",
        "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41gKlxTYnkL._SL500_.jpg"
    },
    {
        "asin": "B00JOW20TY",
        "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/511Ae304D5L._SL500_.jpg"
    }
]
```

We need to loop through above array, download or read image, call an external node api which will accept image as file with multipart/form-data and file type can only be jpg

We wanted to do this without saving files on local server as there will be 100 of such request and don't want to fill up server space.

What we tried so far, we can download image as blob or arrayBuffer like following;

```js
export const downloadImageFromUrl = async(url) => {
  // const response = await fetch({
  //   url,
  //   method: 'GET',
  //   responseType: 'stream'
  // });  
  const response = await axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob'
  });  
  console.log('response ', response)
  //fs.writeFileSync('./temp.jpg', res.data);
  return response;
}
```

But when we send it to node api, it says filetype is blob and reject our request. Can you please advise best approach to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `arraybuffer` response type.

P.S. Blobs are not currently supported by Axios on the Node.js platform;

```js
const response = await axios({
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  });
```

Comment: what should i do with that arraybuffer ? how do i convert it to file without saving it to local disk so i can call another api

Comment: It actually returns a Buffer instance (fs.readFile also returns this type) that can be passed directly to Axios.